# Rewriting line integral for complex-valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

**Context**: Suppose $f = \phi + i\psi$ is continuous and $\gamma(t):[a, b] \to \mathbb{C}$ is a curve. Then we define the integral of $f$ along $\gamma$ to be
$$
\int_\gamma\!f = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\gamma^\prime(t)dt
$$

**Exercise**: Show that
$$
\int_\gamma\!f = \int_\gamma\!\phi(x, y)\,dx - \psi(x, y)\,dy + i \int_\gamma\!\phi(x, y)\,dy + \psi(x, y)\,dx
$$

**Work so far**:

We can write $\gamma(t) = (\gamma^1(t), \gamma^2(t))$ and let $\displaystyle\frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial\gamma^i} = \gamma_i$ and $\displaystyle\frac{d\gamma^i}{dt} = \dot{\gamma}^i$ then we have 
$$
\begin{align*}
  \int_\gamma\!f &= \int_\gamma\!\phi(x, y) + i\psi(x, y)\\
  &= \int_a^b\!\left(\phi(\gamma^1, \gamma^2) + i\psi(\gamma^1, \gamma^2)\right)\gamma^\prime\,dt\\
  &= \int_a^b\!\left(\phi(\gamma^1, \gamma^2) + i\psi(\gamma^1, \gamma^2)\right)\left(\gamma_1\dot{\gamma}^1 + \gamma_2\dot{\gamma}^2\right)\,dt\\
  &= \int_a^b\!\phi\gamma_1\dot{\gamma}^1 + \phi\gamma_2\dot{\gamma}^2 + i\psi\gamma_1\dot{\gamma}^1 + i\psi\gamma_2\dot{\gamma}^2\,dt
\end{align*}
$$

and now I'm trying to bring that last expression into the required form. Ideas I think will be helpful in simplification include $\frac{1}{i} = -i$ and

$$
\int_\gamma\!f\,dx = \int_a^b\!f(\gamma^1, \gamma^2)\dot{\gamma}^1\,dt
$$

but I'm having difficulty seeing where to go from here, and how to resolve the issue of the  various $\gamma_i$ in each term. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\frac{i}{i}$ is 1! Did you mean $\frac{1}{i} = -i$? Thats true.

Comment: @FireGarden yes, thank you. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

If $\gamma = (\gamma^1, \gamma^2)$, then you have $\gamma = \gamma^1 + i\gamma^2$.

Inserting in the integral:
$$
\int_\gamma f = \int_a^b \big( \phi(\gamma^1, \gamma^2) + i\psi(\gamma^1, \gamma^2) \big) (\dot\gamma^1 + i\dot\gamma^2)\,dt
$$

Multiplying:
$$
\int_\gamma f = \int_a^b \big( \phi\dot\gamma^1 + i\psi\dot\gamma^1 + i\phi\dot\gamma^2 +i^2\psi\dot\gamma^2 \big)\,dt
$$

Now, $i^2=-1$, and grouping the $i$'s:
$$
\int_\gamma f = \int_a^b \big( (\phi\dot\gamma^1 -\psi\dot\gamma^2)\,dt + i( \psi\dot\gamma^1 + \phi\dot\gamma^2 )\big) \,dt
$$

Now recall that (in terms of differential forms): $dx = \dot\gamma^1dt$ and $dy = \dot\gamma^2dt$. So:
$$
\int_\gamma f = \int_\gamma \big( (\phi\,dx -\psi\,dy) + i( \psi\,dx + \phi\,dy )\big).
$$